# sql server: getting several records each with several sub records

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have 2 tables, first one contains posts, and the second one contains comments for posts

```
Posts
-------
[ID] int
{Text] nvarchar(max)
.... (some other columns...)

Comments
--------
[ID] int
[PostID] int
[Comment] Nvarchar(1024)
.... (some other columns)
```

I want to load top 20 posts and top 10 comments of each post. the problem is as I'm going to show posts on my page I need comments of each posts after the post.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you get all the data you need in 1 trip. Your `DataAdapter.Fill` command should have something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 20 * FROM Posts WHERE ...
```

And then in the same command, seperated by a semicolon `;`, have your second SQL which will result in a 2nd table being added in your `DataSet`.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         *, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PostID ORDER BY ID desc) RowNum 
     FROM 
         Comments 
     WHERE 
         PostID IN (SELECT TOP 20 ID FROM Posts WHERE ...)
    ) tmp 
WHERE 
    RowNum <= 10
```

This SQL will get you the comments for all the posts you asked for above, but just the last 10 for each PostID.

Note that

```
SELECT TOP 20 ID FROM Posts WHERE ...
```

should be the exact SQL from your first SQL statement except the single return field is the ID column.

After you fill the dataset, save it for later so when the record changes (selects Post), you can then get the data that is already local for your comments

Sorry about this being in VB

```
Dim DRs as Datarow() = {Your Dataset}.Tables(1).Select("PostID = " & {The current records ID})
```

Hope this helps. It should get you at least pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dataset containing two datatables connected with a relation. You can achieve that through Visual Studio designer. You can also use the newer Entity Framework. Alternatively, you can select all the posts, then as you loop through the posts, issue an SQL statement to grab the comments from the DB (rather slow).  You could also grab all the comments at once, then as you loop through the posts, have a nested loop filter out the corresponding comments. You could also use a LINQ query to group comments by post. This particular cat can bs skinned many many ways :-)

Comment: two data tables will of course have a relation but how to read comments of each post. I have thought of opening and colsing a connection after each post that reads comments but wouln't it be slow?